# Postgres insert into table multiple return values from with rows as

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'd like to insert multiple (2) rows into a table in Postgres, and use the ids returned by `WITH ROWS AS` in an insert to another table (columns `id_1` and `id_2` in `second_table`), and return *that* id as the final result of the query.

`first_table` is the main data collection, and `second_table` essentially just links two `first_table` entries together.

Here's the gist of what I'm trying to do:

```
WITH row AS (
        INSERT INTO first_table (some_data, more_data)
        VALUES (DEFAULT, DEFAULT), (DEFAULT, DEFAULT)
        RETURNING first_table_id
        )
INSERT INTO second_table (id_1, id_2, other_data)
VALUES (???, ???, DEFAULT)
RETURNING second_table_id
```

I am using Node.js and the `node-pg` module; I know that this can be done in Node.js by having the first query return the two rows returned by `WITH ROWS AS`, then running another prepared statement using the two ids for the next insert.

I'm not sure if I can do this through a trigger, since `ON INSERT` only has one row. Maybe it would have two since these rows are inserted into `first_table` in the same transaction, but I don't have extensive experience with Postgres/SQL in general so I'm not sure how I could do this via trigger.

The problem I'm having is that the `WITH ROWS AS` statement returns 2 rows (intended, obviously), but I can't figure out how to access each row independently in the next insert, and I have a feeling that it isn't possible.

Can this be accomplished in a **single query**, or do I *have* to use a trigger or Node.js for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second insert needs to be an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM first_cte`. If you can make an assumtion, that the second generated id is larger than the first (or at least, distinct & comparable -- this is the case, if you use PostgreSQL's `serial`, or directly a sequence), you can use aggregation:

```
WITH rows AS (
  INSERT INTO first_table (some_data, more_data)
  VALUES (DEFAULT, DEFAULT), (DEFAULT, DEFAULT)
  RETURNING first_table_id
)
INSERT INTO second_table (id_1, id_2)
SELECT min(first_table_id), max(first_table_id)
FROM rows
RETURNING second_table_id
```

Note that, `other_data` is omitted: you cannot use the `DEFAULT` in `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`.

For a more general solution, you can use arrays:

```
WITH rows AS (
  INSERT INTO first_table (some_data, more_data)
  VALUES (DEFAULT, DEFAULT), (DEFAULT, DEFAULT)
  RETURNING first_table_id
)
INSERT INTO second_table (id_1, id_2, other_data)
SELECT first_table_ids[1], first_table_ids[2], 5 -- value '5' for "other_data"
FROM (
  SELECT array_agg(first_table_id) AS first_table_ids
  FROM rows
) AS rows_as_array
RETURNING second_table_id
```

Comment: Hey pozs, this is exactly what I was looking for! However, is it possible to also include other values in the second `INSERT` (not `DEFAULT`)? For example, I'd like to do: `INSERT INTO translations  (source_id, destination_id, other_data) SELECT min(phrase_id), max(phrase_id) FROM rows, 5`, where `other_data` has an actual value (`5` here). Getting a syntax error though. Is there a correct syntax for this?

Comment: @ChrisCirefice Yes, you just need to include it as a constant column in select, see my edits.

Comment: This is absolutely perfect, exactly what I spent two hours last night trying to figure out the correct syntax for! Thanks :) I am indeed using `serial` as my column id for the first table, so the `min`/`max` solution is a lot simpler and fits my use case. Since there are no similar questions like this on SO (that I could find, anyway), I hope that you get lots of upvotes :) Thanks again!